# HTML Purifier is deleting iframe

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I need to allow to put iframe youtube videos but I'm forcing problems, because when I pass:

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/JTc1mDieQI8" width="640"></iframe>
```

I get:

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

My configuration is:

```
"HTML.SafeIframe" => 'true',
        "URI.SafeIframeRegexp" => "%^(http://|https://|//)(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%",
        'HTML.Allowed' => 'pre[class],iframe'
```

Comment: Did you turn off magic quotes?

Comment: That's all the config I have for this

Comment: OK, but what does your php.ini say about `magic_quotes_gpc`? (By the way, keep in mind that `.` in a regular expression is a wildcard. You probably want to escape those.)

Comment: Magic quotes are turned off, do I need to enable them??